# How to plot a 2-qubit UGate?

Tags: python, sympy

How do I plot a custom 2-qubit gate in SymPy?

The following doesn't seem to work for me:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum.gate import UGate
from sympy.physics.quantum.circuitplot import circuit_plot

g = UGate((0,1), eye(4), 2)     # define custom 2-qubit gate
circuit_plot(g, 2)              # plot circuit
```

Output:

[image]

I expected the gate to be drawn across the 2 qubit wires.